# Using DataTables with Bootstrap theme, jQuery $.get function

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to use DataTable with Bootstrap theme to display my table result (PHP & SQLSRV) where it will be loaded into div using jquery $.get function.

I tried below code but it didn't work. Below is my code for jquery and appreciated if you can provide me some solutions here.

CSS on Header order:

1. Bootstrap
2. DataTables Bootstrap
3. Fontawesome
4. Datepicker
5. style

JS on footer order

1. jquery
2. bootstrap
3. jquery.datatables
4. dataTables.bootstrap
5. datepicker3
6. custom

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#getData").on('click', function () {
       var report = $(this).val();
       if (report == 'tput') {
           var tputpage = 'reports/dtput.php', dstrt = $('#from_date').val(), dend = $('#to_date').val();
           $.get(tputpage, {
               dstrt:dstrt, dend:dend
           }, function (data) {
               $('.target').html(data,function(){
                   $('table').dataTable();
               });
           });
       } });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html()` method only takes one argument. It can be a dom object, string, jQuery object or a function.

You don't want function for your purpose as you want to pass in the html received from ajax request

try doing it this way

```
$('.target').html(data);
$('table').dataTable();
```

**[html() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Comment: great, if it helped feel free to approve the answer